# Spring Boot Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, easymock

I have the following code. I do believe that I create the beans properly but I keep getting this "Error creating bean with name...:Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field..."

The code builds and runs well without the tests. But I need the tests...

I've been searching high and low and no solution seems to work for me. I've been dealing with this error for a while now, so any help would be great!

```
@Service(value = "serviceA")
public class ServiceA{

     @Autowired
     private ServiceB

     ...

}

@Service(value="serviceB")
public class ServiceB{
  
     ...

}

@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration({"/app-name-mocks.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestingClass{
     
     @Autowired
     private ServiceA serviceA;

     @Autowired
     private ServiceB serviceB;

     ...
     
}

app-name-mocks.xml:

<bean id="serviceA" class="com.appname.service.ServiceA" />

<bean id="serviceB" class="org.easymock.EasyMock" 
      factory-method="createNiceMock">
      <constructor-arg name ="toMock"
          value="com.appName.service.ServiceB"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Maybe not related but you use `constructor-arg` but you don't have it (or show it)

And  the error show the of use of field not contructor expressed through field``

Comment: Can you post the full exception that you are getting, with stacktrace?

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? Is it required to use XML?
I'm thinking you may be able to import the beans directly with the 
@Import({ServiceA.class, ServiceB.class})

Comment: OR @ContextConfiguration(classes = { ServiceA.class, ServiceB.class })

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Easymock isn't playing nice with Spring boot so I'll have to change stuff around and clean up the project a bit. Thank you everyone!

Comment: I should play nice. What was the exception?